# Three JS creating custom 3d geometry

Tags: three.js

Is there any way to define shape in 3d like

var x = 0, y = 0, ***z=0*** ;

var heartShape = new THREE.***Shape***();

heartShape.moveTo( x + 25, y + 25,***z*** );

heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x + 25, y + 25, ***z***,x + 20, y,**z**, x, y,***z*** );

heartShape.bezierCurveTo( x - 30, y,***z***, x - 30, y + 35, ,***z***,x - 30,y + 35,***z-30*** );
....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go through this example for various shape creation....
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_shapes

Comment: Thanks for an answer. It is all 2d Shape declarations.

Comment: yes, its all 2D declaration, with extrude geometry and extrudesetting they have created 3d shapes... ( check the example code line no - 87)..  also Three.Shape() is designed for 2d shapes drivenby/using paths...

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. The codes I have written are from the same example you are referring. I am looking to create shape in 3d. So either I have to use an existing library if available or create a new one.